# Android testing for null and condition

Tags: java, testing, null

Ola,

Android/JAVA question, I need to test if a object is not NULL and if it's not NULL check a value, thus avoiding runtime error. As my vb.net background I'm used to;

`if (not BackgroundWorker1 = nothing) andalso (backgroundworker.status = running) then`

Is there a charming, 'one IF'/single line way to do this in JAVA?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm guessing than in your example `BackgroundWorker1` and `backgroundworker` are intended to be the same thing?

Comment: Yup, typo, sorry, very sharp!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a pretty direct translation:

```
if (BackgroundWorker1 != null && Backgroundworker1.status == running)
{
    // "then" part here
}
```

Just like VB's `andalso` operator, Java also uses short-circuit evaluation with its logical operators.

Answer (score 1):

Sure,

```
if ( backgroundWorker != null && backgroundWorker.status == running ) {
```

works in Java since the statements are evaluated from left to right.

Answer (score 0):

The moral equivalent of `andAlso` in Basic is `&&` in Java. Note, that there is no easy equivalent to plain `and` (i.e., the non-short-circuit version of the logical operator).

Comment: There is a non-short-circuit version of `&&` in Java.  It's `&`.

Comment: @Luke - Just out of curiousity, I looked up the specification of `&` when used on boolean operands in the JLS. And I learned something new today. Thank you (seriously). http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/first_edition/html/15.doc.html#5242